# Lightning Community Does Not Support pubsub for Lightning Web Components?

Tags: lightning-community, lightning-web-components

Has anyone successfully used the pubsub module from lwc-recipes to enable inter-component communication in a Lightning Community?  The registerListener function in the pubsub module throws an error because the pageRef property is undefined.  Or is pubsub designed for Lightning Experience only?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pub-sub module checks for page references when firing events, so that the event is scoped and only in the current page.

In Communities, we actually now support lightning-navigation as of Spring '19: http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_networks_navigationchanges.htm

However, there are some limitations, currently CurrentPageReference in LWC is not supported like: `@wire(CurrentPageReference)currentPageReference;`, which is why you are getting undefined page references. We are currently working on supporting it, so it should be out soon!

For a temporary solution, you can just remove all the pageRef checking in pubsub :). Here's a quick example: https://gist.github.com/kmesic/262887799fb70be94707cb0b87936e7b

Also, we are soon going to be releasing a LWC sample that will work in Communities by default! This should help clear up any confusion when using LWC in Communities.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kenan!  That's great news.

Comment: @kenan, is this being supported natively now.

Answer (score 3):

Pub - Sub model uses Page reference and [lightning-navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) and as lightning - navigation is supported only in Lightning Experience and Mobile App, the pub - sub module currently won't work in communities.

Src : https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/issues/86

Comment: Adding to this, even the aura version doesn't support community context so it's unlikely the LWC would too.